# Can sunspot-solr filter_by nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr, sunspot

Let's say I have People, and People has_many Watermelon .

I have a filter_by that can work for People attributes, for example :

```
:filter_by => 'has_eaten_today'
```

But can I do a `:filter_by` for the nested attribute of Watermelon? For example :

```
:filter_by => 'watermelons.created_at'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question came from me not really understanding Sunspot-solr, but its quite easy.

Just target the nested attributes from your model :

```
def watermelon_time
  self.watermelon.created_at
end
```

Then add that to

```
searchable do
  time :watermelon_time
..
```

Then my controller :

```
query.with(:watermelon_time).equal_to(params[:filter_by] == 'watermelon_time' ? 'true' : false) if params[:filter_by]
```

Extra Bonus :

Added a link to write this functionality in my :

```
= link_to 'Watermelon Time', url_for(:overwrite_params => { :filter_by => 'watermelon_time', :page => nil })
```

Bon Appetite!